# why query can't execute?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i'm passive english..
I have an database connection

```
           String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TRANSAKSI
                    + " (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota ) " + " VALUES ( '"
                    + kdCabang + "' , '" + cursor.getString(0) + "' , '"
                    + noNota + "'";

            dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);
            Log.d("INSERT noNota", sql);
```

I think my code already true.. but in my log cat...

```
09-08 15:23:53.811: ERROR/Database(21975): Failure 1 (near "'1'": syntax error) on 0x343fc0 when preparing 'INSERT INTO TRANSAKSI (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota )  VALUES ( 'TKRS' , 'KRKJ' , '1''.
```

anyone can tell my fault?
thanks be4

Answer (score 6):

**You're missing a closing parenthesis.**

Should be:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TRANSAKSI
                    + " (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota ) " + " VALUES ( '"
                    + kdCabang + "' , '" + cursor.getString(0) + "' , '"
                    + noNota + "')";
```

to produce:

```
'INSERT INTO TRANSAKSI (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota )  VALUES ( 'TKRS' , 'KRKJ' , '1')'.
```

It's all in the error message - you need to learn to read and understand them.

Answer (score 3):

You have not closed the bracket at the end
Please check line no 4

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TRANSAKSI
                    + " (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota ) " + " VALUES ( '"
                    + kdCabang + "' , '" + cursor.getString(0) + "' , '"
                    + noNota + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

close the parentheses of Values as below

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TRANSAKSI
                    + " (kdCabang, kdRoti, noNota ) " + " VALUES ( '"
                    + kdCabang + "' , '" + cursor.getString(0) + "' , '"
                    + noNota + "')";
```